# Автоматически оставлять комент под постом телеграмм telethon/pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

друзья. У меня тут возник вопросик: как через telethon или pyrogram (без разницы) оставлять коменты под постами в телеграмм каналах ? К примеру, вышел пост, и скрипт автоматически оставляет комент.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import filters

api_id = 0000000 
api_hash = ""
txt = """здесь пишем текст комментария"""

app = Client("auto_comment_sender", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
channel: int = -1001312562000  #id канала
chat: int = -1001404922000  #id чата, в котором собираются комментарии канала
texted = 0


@app.on_message(filters=filters.chat([channel, channel_chat]))
async def main(client, message):
    global texted
    async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id=channel, limit=-1, offset_id=-1):  # Тут ид канала
        texted = message.text
        async for msg in app.get_chat_history(chat_id=channel_chat, limit=-1, offset_id=-1):  # Тут ид чата
                if msg.text == texted: 
                    texted = 0
                    await msg.reply(txt)
                else:
                    continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('[Activate]')
    app.run()
```